# problem with displaying deleted records using plsql

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlplus

I'm deleting records whose number (`nr_br`) is greater than **2** and then I need to display the numbers (`nr_br`) of deleted records.

```sql
DECLARE
  nr_branch NUMBER(10);
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM branch WHERE nr_br > 2;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('deleted records: ' || TO_CHAR(SQL%ROWCOUNT));
  IF SQL%FOUND THEN
    SELECT nr_br INTO nr_branch FROM branch;
  END IF;
END;
/
```

I have a problem to construct an appropriate if condition for displaying deleted records.

Answer (score 3):

You can use **RETURNING INTO** clause along with a LOOP such as

```sql
DECLARE
  v_nrbr branch.nrbr%TYPE;
BEGIN
  FOR c IN ( SELECT * FROM branch WHERE nrbr > 2 )
  LOOP  
    DELETE branch WHERE nrbr = c.nrbr RETURNING c.nrbr INTO v_nrbr;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('deleted record: ' ||v_nrbr);
  END LOOP;
END;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8c496470c6bba84e79cb1aa2a8cbe334)</kbd>

**Edit** : You can rewrite the code block considering the case for the occurence of the duplicate values of `nrbr` as

```sql
DECLARE
  v_nrbr branch.nrbr%TYPE;
BEGIN
  FOR c IN ( SELECT * FROM branch WHERE nrbr > 2 ORDER BY nrbr )
  LOOP  
    DELETE branch WHERE nrbr = c.nrbr RETURNING MAX(c.nrbr) INTO v_nrbr;
    IF v_nrbr IS NOT NULL THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('deleted record: ' ||v_nrbr);
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END;  
/
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8cfe0a31eea3cdffbdd2592cd612c89a)</kbd>

Comment: Nice idea with the RETURNING clause!

Comment: It works *fine* in case the column `nrbr` is *unique*, but fails with `ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows` is case of duplicates. The fact of deleting everything *higher than two* does not suggest that this is a *sequence*. (Only a suggestion - otherwise nice solution!)

Comment: Exactly..! thank you @MarmiteBomber , I've added the related case ...